# apps and google play cannot connect to the internet after rooting

Tags: rooting

My phone is a samsung s duos gt s7562. I rooted my phone recently. But Iam having some problems after that. My apps, except for opera mini and instagram, cannot connect to data services. I tried factory resetting, enabling background data and even unrooting but of no use. Only the above mentioned apps are working. But when I am accessing internet through wifi everything works fine.I got a hunch that may be it has something to do with the busybox i installed. When I was installing it, it gave a lot of things to install when I selected advanced installation but i ignored it and selected the normal one where the busybox installer will select the necessary stuff and install it.

Anyone got any remedy to this??? Please help because I am fed of searching for remedies.... Nothing helped so far

Answer (score 1):

Be sure and check your Date.   Had problems with google play suddenly stopped working.   After trying multiple suggestions, realized the date was reset back to 2008.   Once reset, things started working again.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these steps.

1. Root your Android phone by using super su nd root checker
2. Download [Lucky Patcher](https://www.luckypatchers.com/download/)
3. Grant root to Lucky Patcher
4. Then go to toolbox
5. and click on block ads options
6. and then click on "clear the local hosts file" option
7. All done, come back to home and reboot your Android

Hope this helps. Do this on your own responsibility.